# Is is possible to add a calculative property based on the sibling class property C#?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class of type:

```
public class sample
{
    public int id;
    public string s;
    //Need a calculative property based on sibling value
    //Ex. public float CharRatio
}
```

consider the following data set

```
List<sample> s = new List<sample>();
s.Add(new sample{id = 1, s = "source"}); //id 1 is always source charRatio 100 since 6/6 in percentage
s.Add(new sample{id = 2, s = "test"}); //charRatio = 66
s.Add(new sample{id = 3, s = "test"}); //charRatio = 66
s.Add(new sample{id = 4, s = "test"}); //charRatio = 66
```

Is it possible to add a calculative property to the class which will calculate a value based on the value of the sibling in a collection using LINQ/LAMBDA or any work around.
I am trying to find a way to add charRatio which is calculated using:

```
charRatio = source.Len/test.Len
```

source is identified using the Id, which is always 1.
My requirement needs it to be a calculative property so i can use it in  a expression tree.

Comment: To be clear, you basically want `1/  where(s == "test").Count`? Or is it the length of "source" / length of "test"

Comment: @janzen I have edited the question with the required comments! I basically want to calculate charRatio by finding source string length and divide it by all the string length, I hope the comments are clear

Comment: @Comraid you can check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a property whose value is calculated based on the given properties / values. I hope I understand what you asked properly. Let me know if it does not match your need. I also tried to write as many comments as possible. So let the code do the talking :)

```
public class Sample {

    /// <summary>
    /// This sourcestring is set to the same value of Sample with Id = 1
    /// </summary>
    private string _sourceStringOfSampleWithId1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Sample instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Id of Sample</param>
    /// <param name="source">Source of Sample</param>
    public Sample(int id, string source) {
        Id = id;
        Source = Source;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Id of Sample
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Source of Sample
    /// </summary>
    public string Source { get; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculative property for CharRatio
    /// </summary>
    public double CharRatio => (double)_sourceStringOfSampleWithId1.Length / Source.Length * 100;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets SourceString of Sample with Id = 1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceString"></param>
    public void SetSourceString(string sourceString) {
        _sourceStringOfSampleWithId1 = sourceString;
    }

}
```

Here is how you use it:

```
List<Sample> sampleList = new List<Sample>(); // Creates a sample list
sampleList.Add(new Sample(1, "source")); //id 1 is always source charRatio 100 since 6/6 in percentage
sampleList.Add(new Sample(2, "test")); //charRatio = 66
sampleList.Add(new Sample(3, "test")); //charRatio = 66
sampleList.Add(new Sample(4, "test")); //charRatio = 66
var sampleWithId1 = sampleList.Find(s=>s.Id == 1); // Find sample with Id = 1
sampleList.ForEach(s=>s.SetSourceString(sampleWithId1.Source)); // Set all samples calcualtive source string to Sample with Id =1
var ratio = sampleList[2].CharRatio; //66.66; // Get an example from list and see char ratio
```

Based on the comments, here is an edited version of Sample class. I am keeping the original answer as well. So use whichever fits your use-case. I will not comment this case, as it should be obvious from the original answer.

```
public class SampleWithStaticField {

    private static string _sourceStringOfSampleWithId1;
    public SampleWithStaticField(int id, string source) {
       Id = id;
       Source = Source;
       // Set static source string which will be shared between all instances
        if(Id == 1) {
            _sourceStringOfSampleWithId1 = source;
       }
    }
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Source { get; }
    public double CharRatio {
        get {
            if(_sourceStringOfSampleWithId1 == null) {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(_sourceStringOfSampleWithId1)} is not set!");
            }
            return (double)_sourceStringOfSampleWithId1.Length / Source.Length * 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you can use it

```
var sampleList = new List<Sample>();
sampleList.Add(new Sample(1, "source")); //id 1 is always source charRatio 100 since 6/6 in percentage
sampleList.Add(new Sample(2, "test")); //charRatio = 66
sampleList.Add(new Sample(3, "test")); //charRatio = 66
sampleList.Add(new Sample(4, "test")); //charRatio = 66
var ratio = sampleList[2].CharRatio; //66.66;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I would have to use this inside another class! since the sample class is related to my main class by one to many relationship! do you think its right to use loop on setting the value?! is there a way to have a shared variable within a collection? that can be set when the string with source id is set? that would eliminate the usage of loop, but I'm not sure if thats possible but i'm open for suggestions

Comment: @Comraid, well you can go for a static variable, which can be accessed by all Sample instances. Then each sample class can access the static value and you would not need to use foreach

Comment: but wont the static variable be sample across all the collections? I want a variable to be shared between a each set of collections!, is it possible to restrict that?

Comment: @Comraid, yes that is correct. static variable will be shared between all `Sample` classes. Simply, if you have an identifier, such as a unique name for each collection, then you can use a dictionary too

Comment: @Comraid, If I were you I would add another layer of abstraction at `List<Sample>` level such as `SampleCollection` and your life will become so much easier

Comment: That could work! but there's no way to restrict a static variable just for the collection right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222935/discussion-between-hasan-emrah-sungu-and-comraid).

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be like this if the `id = 1` of the list will always be the basis of source and it is **UNIQUE**

```
public class sample
{
    public int id {get; set;
    public string s {get; set;}
    public float ratio {get; set;}
}


var list = new List<sample>();
//same values you listed
//...
//...
```

then i would add the ratio by `foreach` like

```
var sourceObject = list.First(x => x.Id == 1);
var result = list.ForEach(x => {
    
   if (x.Id == sourceObject.Id)
   {
       x.ratio = 1;
   }
   else
   {
       x.ratio = x.s.Length/sourceObject.Length * 100
   }
    
});
```

Comment: If possible always go for immutable properties

Comment: Thanks for your response but i was kinda looking for something without looping!